# How inefficient are nested while loops in python?

Tags: python, json, facebook, while-loop

I am trying to return a list of comments to Facebook posts. In some cases, the comments themselves also have replies which are in a nested list in the JSON I'm taking as "commentraw". I don't want to just return the raw data and format that the JSON is in, as in some cases I do transformation or reorganization. I believe that the data format is the same for both comments and replies but the replies do not always appear. Anyway, to accomplish this I have come up with this function:

```
def get_post_comments(commentraw, graphsession):
    graph=graphsession
    commentlist=[]
    i=0

    while(i<len(commentraw['data'])):
        entry={'id': commentraw['data'][i]['id'], 'created_time': convert_date(commentraw['data'][i]['created_time']), 'message': commentraw['data'][i]['message']}
        replyraw=graph.get_connections(id=commentraw['data'][i]['id'], connection_name='comments', summary=True)
        if replyraw['data']:#if theres replies to the comment on the post, do a nested while (yuck) to also grab and format the replies - this is probably insanely inefficient
            y=0
            replylist=[]
            while(y<len(replyraw['data'])):
                subentry={'created_time': convert_date(replyraw['data'][y]['created_time']), 'id': replyraw['data'][y]['id'], 'message': replyraw['data'][y]['message'], 'from': replyraw['data'][y]['from']}
                replylist.append(subentry)
                y=y+1
            entry['replies']=replylist
        commentlist.append(entry)
        i=i+1

    return commentlist
```

So basically because this is a JSON input with lists for N number of comments or replies, I use a while loop and increment to make sure I iterate over all items in the list. However, because the replies to comments are embedded in the JSON, I have to embed a while loop in my while loop to iterate over all the potential data.

Facebook can potentially have A LOT of data. How inefficient is my solution (i.e. nested while loops)? I have a lurking suspicion that recursion may be possible here but I am a novice Python coder.

Comment: Profile it with `timeit` and see if it's fast enough for you. There's no point in wasting time optimizing something if downloading the data is probably going to take 1000x longer.

Comment: By this you mean throughout the solution I devise put in timing checkpoints as that will instruct me on where the slowest portions are? Or are you saying try writing this function a different way and see which is faster?

Comment: Python has pretty decent profiling tools. `timeit` is built in and you can test the performance of this function alone. There is also [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler), which can provide a breakdown per-line.

Comment: For-loops and the equivalent while-loop will be exactly as *inefficient* from an algorithmic complexity point of view, however, for-loops are *much* faster than the equivalent `while` loop in Python.

Comment: for-loops would also make this code much less verbose.

Comment: You're program gets exponentially more and more inefficient as you nest loops, look into big O notation if you want to understand more about this